# Wait for download method to finish before running next .then - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download

I am trying to practice node by building a small application that allows a user to download a file.

I have saved the file on S3, saved the url in a mLab DB, and want to download the file to the app so I can use the url as an `href` on the client side. It currently works, to a point, but downloads an empty file. Which I think is due to the fact that it is running the next `then()` before the file has downloaded.

This is the code I currently have:

```
(async err => {
    const charge = await stripe.charges
      // create stripe charge
      .create({
       ...
      })
      // when the payment is successful, 
      // download the file locally to a 'dist' folder
      // so we can use it on the success page
      .then(() => {
        download(url_to_file, "dist").then(() => {
          console.log("done!");
        });
      })
      // then render the success page
      .then(
        res.render("success", {
          fileUrl: ...
        })
      )
```

So on the client I can (using ejs) do something like:

`<a href="<%= /dist/fileUrl %>">Download</a>`

I am very new to promises and not sure how to wait for the download method to completely finish before running the next then and rendering the success page.

At the moment, the method runs, then the success page renders, then the file appears in the app. This allows the file to be downloaded but the file is empty.

Can anybody point me in the right direction / explain how to wait for the download to finish before running the next `.then()` method? Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Try returning the call to `download`; e.g.: `.then(() => {
        return download(url_to_file, "dist").then(() => {
          console.log("done!");
        });
      })`

Comment: Hi @ScottRudiger, thanks for the reply. This downloads the file correctly, but the file is still empty when downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, just `return` the promise from the `download`.

**Without `return`**

```js
Promise.resolve().then(()=> {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done 1');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('done 2');
});
```

**With `return`**

```js
Promise.resolve().then(()=> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done 1');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('done 2');
});
```

Comment: Hi @Mosh, appciate the reply. I've just wrapped the download in a Promise but when logging it all, it starts the download, renders the success page, then finishes the download. 

`.then(() => {
   Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
         console.log("Started download");
         return download(fileUrl, "dist").then(() => {
            console.log("downloaded!");
         });
         resolve();
      });
   });
}).then(...)`

Comment: i was using the resolve() in the wrong place. It now runs all the methods in the correct order, however the file that is downloaded is still empty. When looking the project folder it is definitely there and looks fine so not sure why it's saying its empty when it downloads

Comment: Well, this is a different issue. I have no enough info to try to figure it out. If you try to get the file directly from the `url_to_file` (using the brwoser or something) do you get the right file?

Comment: Yeh when I console.log it, it says its the correct url, and in the actual project folder it's showing correctly and the file (mp3) plays when I open it, but for some reason the file that is downloaded from the browser is empty.

Comment: How the `download` method looks like? Is it from a 3rd party package?

Comment: Yeh i'm using the node download package (npm download), so the method is: `download(req.body.total_source, "dist").then(() => {
                  console.log("downloaded!");
                  resolve();
                });`

Comment: fixed the empty file issue in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982960/node-download-method-produces-empty-file

Comment: Glad to hear :)